# Voltage detector with ajustable time delay in a THT package or build own simple small time delay?

Tags: delay, voltage-detector

For my project I need to delay the enable signal from an esp32 for a 50MHz clock by a bit - The examples I use on how to do that only ever use a [BD523](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/voltage_detector/bd5xxxg-2m-e.pdf) with non-inverted output. For testing I want to build this on a perfboard because the guide I followed (and experience I made) don't allow me to use a breadboard as the 50MHz signal doesn't work with it.

I tried to search for a part on RS but I simply couldn't find one that was ideal for my purpose.

Does someone have an idea on how I could implement that on my own ?

As for why:
The ESP32 signal goes into PIN0(can't change because it's the EMAC CLK Pin) which is also a strapping pin to enable to programming if pulled LOW. I already put a 10K pull-up on the pin. The clock get's powered by the 3V3 out from the ESP32 so in a 50/50 chance the PIN0 is either HIGH or LOW on startup depending on the clock which I don't want. I need to delay the 3V3 clock enable for a few (milli)seconds so it doesn't load into the boot mode.

Example on how it is made with a BD523 (here with PoE wich I don't need/have) [WESP32](https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/853893653282976/wESP32-1.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use whatever voltage supervisor you find with a reset delay. They make them in open drain, push-pull, active high, low, almost every combination you can think off. I'd say you need a forced-pull up on reset for this application (after that it goes idle).